# Show $\lim_{x\uparrow L}T(x)=\infty$ where $T(x)=\inf\{t\geq 0 :f(t)>x\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be an continuous, non-decreasing function with $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L<\infty$ with $f(x)<L$ $\forall x\geq 0$.

Define

$$T(x)=\inf\{t\geq 0 :f(t)>x\} \text{ on } [0,L).$$

Prove that that $\lim_{x\uparrow L}T(x)=\infty$.

---

Here is my thinking: I know that the function is increasing, so if I send $x$ up to $L$, its going to take infinitely long to reach it, as there will always be more to travel. How can I prove this rigorously? I can't figure out how to formalize the proof.
Maybe if I assume $\lim_{x\uparrow L}T(x)<\infty$ and try by contradiction?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is continuous and increasing, it has an inverse function. Note that if $x \in [0, \infty)$, then $f(x)\in [0, L)$.

Comment: Presumably increasing means strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $t_* := \lim_{x\uparrow L} T(x)$ is finite. Since $T(x)$ is nondecreasing in $x$, this means that

$$ T(x) \leq t_* $$

for all $x \in [0, L)$.

Now let $s > t_*$ be arbitrary. In light of the definition of $T(x)$ and the monotonicity of $f$, the above inequality implies that $f(s) > x$. Since this is true for all $x \in [0, L)$, letting $x \uparrow L$ gives $f(s) \geq L$, contradicting the assumption.

(*Remark.* If 'increasing' means 'nondecreasing' and if the condition $f(x)<L$ for all $x\geq 0$ is dropped, then it is indeed possible that $\lim_{x\uparrow L} T(x) < \infty$.)